# jQuery mobile listview('refresh') doesn't complete enhancement

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, refresh

I have a listview, all nicely displayed.  I add an item to it, using the exact same function I used to put the original items in it with.  If I don't refresh the listview, the new item doesn't get enhanced (no surprise there).  But when I DO call refresh, the enhancement is incomplete.

Here's the item as entered:

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain" id="flip-li-38">
  <div class="containing-element">
    <label for="flip-38">A B:</label>
    <select name="flip-38" id="flip-38" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
      <option value="off">Absent</option>
      <option value="on">Present</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</li>
```

Here's the item after enhancement:

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain" id="flip-li-38" class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
  <div class="containing-element">
    <label for="flip-38">A B:</label>
    <select name="flip-38" id="flip-38" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
      <option value="off">Absent</option>
      <option value="on">Present</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</li>
```

But here's one of the items originally in the list:

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain" id="flip-li-37" class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
<div class="containing-element">
  <label for="flip-37" id="flip-37-label" class="ui-slider">X Y:</label>
  <select name="flip-37" id="flip-37" data-role="slider" data-mini="true" class="ui-slider-switch">
    <option value="off">Absent</option>
    <option value="on">Present</option>
  </select>
  <div role="application" class="ui-slider ui-slider-switch ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-slider-mini" style>
    <span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-a ui-btn-active ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 0%; ">Present</span>
    <span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-b ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 100%; ">Absent</span>
    <div class="ui-slider-inneroffset">
      <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-slider-handle-snapping" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuenow="off" aria-valuetext="Absent" title="Absent" aria-labelledby="flip-37-label" style="left: 0%; ">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">…</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
```

Here's the surrounding context:

```
    <div id="memberPage" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
         <form>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="memberList"></ul>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /content -->
  </div>
```

There might be some kind of timing issue; I captured the partially-enhanced item by writing it to the console, but wrote it BEFORE the call to refresh (which, if I leave the call to refresh out, logs the original unenhanced item).

If it matters, the item gets added from a dialog through the onclick property of a button that links back to the page with the list (thus closing the dialog).

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `$('#memberList').trigger('create');` instead of `refresh` method of listview. I think it might work as you have to enhance not only the new list item but also the slider inside it.

Comment: That ALMOST did the trick; I needed to do both a trigger/create (which got the slider enhanced properly) AND a listview/refresh (which finished the enhancement of the list item).