# Dynamic listview with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile

I have an issue with the refresh of a jquery mobile listview.

This code works fine:

```
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {

   // Generating a dynamic list
       for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
           var link = '<li><a href="#">'+list[i].name+'</a></li>';
           $("#listview").append(link);
       }

   // Listview refresh
   $("#myPage").on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
       try {
           $("#listview").listview('refresh');
       } catch (e) {
           $("#listview").listview();
       }
   });

   $.mobile.changePage($(#myPage), {
        transition:"slide",
        dataUrl:url,
        allowSamePageTransition:true,
        reverse:reverse
    });
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

However, I need to dynamically add an icon to list view items which are in user's favorites. I use a function which returns an array by a request to the local database.

```
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {

  getFavs(function(favsArray){       

     // Generating dynamic list with image
       for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
           favImg = "";
           if(favsArray.indexOf(list[i].id) !== -1){
               favImg = '<img src="images/star-36-black.png" class="ui-li-icon" />';
           }               
           var link = '<li><a href="#">'+favImg+list[i].name+'</a></li>';
           $("#listview").append(link);
       }

       // Listview refresh
       $("#myPage").on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
          try {
              $("#listview").listview('refresh');
          } catch (e) {
              $("#listview").listview();
          }
       });

  });

   $.mobile.changePage($(#myPage), {
        transition:"slide",
        dataUrl:url,
        allowSamePageTransition:true,
        reverse:reverse
    });
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

In this second case, `Listview()` is not applied. I don't understand why this second option is so different that it breaks `Listview()`...

Comment: Have you tried `create`?

Comment: I just discovered `create`; I didn't find it in the api doc, but [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/page-trigger-create-listview-create-refresh-confusion). Using it, I just have a partial CSS support (font-color and font-weight).

Comment: You might need to create them once only.

Comment: It might be created twice as it is binded to pagebeforechange. How could I create it once ?

Comment: You're binding then to pagebeforechange and pagebeforeshow. You need to bind them to one event.

Comment: Yes, I had replaced the whole 'Listview refresh' code by `$("#listview").bind('create');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574585/jquery-mobile-listviewrefresh-doesnt-complete-enhancement?rq=1), although the solution differs. On the second option, I just have to remove the binding to `pagebeforshow`:

```
   // Listview refresh
      try {
          $("#listview").listview('refresh');
      } catch (e) {
          $("#listview").listview();
      }
```

However, I did not yet understand why the binding to `pagebeforeshow` is required in the first option, whereas it breaks the code in the second option...